# Print recursively binary number of given length

Tags: java, recursion

Here, what I have tried.

```
public class PrintBinaryNum {
    
    public static void printBinary(int  num[],int k,int index)
    {
        if(index == k)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num));
            return;
        }
        
        for(int i =index;i<k;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
            {
                num[i] = j;
                printBinary(num, k, i+1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[2];
        printBinary(a, 2, 0);

    }

}
```

I am getting below output:

```
[0, 0]
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
```

Here, result `[1, 0]` and `[1, 1]` are getting printed twice.
I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i =index;i<k;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<=1;j++)
```

Debug your code. Which involves going through the code with your hands and eyeballs and writing down what you think will happen.

Then, if that actually isn't what you wanted, or, it IS what you wanted, but when you run the code, the code doesn't do what you think it does?

You found one bug, fix it, keep going until the code does precisely what you wanted it to do.

Here, simply looking at it you already realize that on the 'top level' invocation, when `index` is 0, this loops 'index' times, and within each loop, it'll loop twice (0, and 1, for `j`). Within this loop (which runs k*2 times), you invoke yourself, with an index closer to the end point.

recursion acts a lot like a for loop. Taking that into consideration, you have **3** loops here.

That's clearly one too many.

SOLUTION: Get rid of one of them. Most likely you want to either get rid of the `for (int i = index`) loop entirely, OR you want to get rid of recursion.

If this is 'write this with recursion' homework, get rid of the loop. Otherwise, get rid of the recursion, because for loops are more efficient, easier to follow, and more java-like.